# Error When Using android and Firebase for Gmail Sign-In in APK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an application in Android Studio that uses Jetpack Compose and Firebase within Jetpack. The app allows users to sign in with their Gmail accounts. However, I'm encountering an issue where I'm unable to use the app on another phone as an APK(generated signed apk).

BeginSignInOperation] Operation started. [CONTEXT service_id=212 ]
2023-08-25 17:59:10.809 20122-19835 Auth.Api.Credentials    com.google.android.gms               W  [BeginSignInOperation] Operation failed. [CONTEXT service_id=212 ]
dcqe: dcqe: dcqe: dcqe: dcqe: dcqe: atkb
at atoc.apply(:com.google.android.gms@233116037@

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly can cause that, but here is a working [example](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d). Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).